# Creating Wind/Dust storm effect animations with cycles?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, effects

Currently i am into still images, but i am starting to get into animation and i was wondering is there a way to create a dust storm like effect with the particles moveing so that it could give the appearance of flight? and is there also a way to create the effect of the fast spinning Propeller. Thanks Guys[image: Model]

Comment: It would be really great if you posted this as two separate questions. You can post as many questions as you like.

Comment: To make things easier for future users looking for similar unfornation, please [edit] your post and make it only one question. The other one please ask as a new question.

Comment: Particle simulation with turbulence force fields is one way, also consider using the smoke simulation.  And for the prop, just spin fast and turn on motion blur if you're using cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would like to mention that the plane looks amazing :D

For the propeller, you could use motion blur and rotate the blade extremely fast. You could also simply download a photo from the internet and rotate it every few frames.

The dust/wind, that is going to be more complicated...

You will need to create a plane and give it a particle simulation. Disable the gravity and give it some Brownian for more effect. Stretch the particles for motion blur (or just enable it under Render Settings).

For added effect, Create a massive cube and give it a Volume Scatter node for the Volume, whilst disabling the Surface node.

Since I had nothing better to do, I created a .blend ;)

[image]

Didn't focus on the material that much...

Comment: please don't use pasteall.org to upload files, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com instead. Links in pasteall expire after a few months. After that, your answer will not be as useful.

Comment: A blurred prop image may be faster to render, But if you're using cycles motion blur already in your dust particles, just animate the prop rotation fast (in curve editor) that'll look better from all angles too. For the particles, nice. Though I would test using a turbulence force field so particles flowed together more, vs Brownian which goes a random direction. Perhaps place limited ones near the end of the wings/props and behind the craft...Also experiment with smoke simulation. BUT before all this, start with reference images/video of what you're trying to emulate, then we can help better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Only been using Blender for 4 years now

Answer (score 1):

You could use particles to simulate this.
This YouTube video is bound to help you as well as this dust tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjI9hTWQxV4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmrCoGj9m2Y

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qr5jKazOT94

Best wishes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the type of particles he wants. He wants the plane to be in a sandstorm, not in a room calmly collecting dust